# CSS Border Shadow On One Side Of the Border

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

Hi guys i need to make a shadowy heading like this, i am unable to understand how can i make it. this is what i am able to get so far, my real concern is the shadow at the end of lines. Thanks

```css
.divider {
    color: #282837;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 20px auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 400;
}


.divider:before, .divider:after {
    content: "";
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 15%;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #9A9A9A;
    margin: 0 2% 0 -55%;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="divider">MEET OUR <span class="divider-2"> TEAM</span></h1>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

to do this, you have to use position property and use background image instead of border

```css
.divider {
    color: #282837;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 20px auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 400;
position: relative;
}

.divider-2 { color: red; }

.divider:before {
    content: "";
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 15%;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #9A9A9A;
position: absolute;
top: 20px;
left: 0px;
}

.divider:after {
content: "";
vertical-align: middle;
display: inline-block;
width: 15%;
border-bottom: 1px dashed #9A9A9A;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 20px;}
```

```html
<h1 class="divider">MEET OUR <span class="divider-2"> TEAM</span></h1>
```

Comment: how can i make dashed lines blurry from side just like in design ?

Comment: instead of border use  background image

Comment: i am new can u guide me how ?

Comment: you have to create one image like that shadow and call that image as background-image for pseudo classes :before and :after.

Comment: i cropped those images from psd and included in content: url() and got the desired result, thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.divider {
color: #282837;
position:relative;
width: 70%;
margin: 20px auto;
overflow: hidden;
text-align: center;
line-height: 1.2em;
font-size: 30px;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-weight: 400;
}
 .divider:before, .divider:after {
content: "";
width: 15%;
border-bottom: 1px dashed #9A9A9A;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.divider:after {
right: 0;
}
.divider:before {
left: 0;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="divider">MEET OUR <span class="divider-2"> TEAM</span></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.divider {
    color: #282837;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 20px auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 400;
}


.divider:before, .divider:after {
    content: "";
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 15%;
    height: 1px;
     background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 50%, #ffffff 50%),  
                 linear-gradient(to right, #ffffff, #000000);
     background-size: 8px 1px, 100% 1px;
     margin: 0;
}
.divider:after {
     background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 50%, #ffffff 50%),  
                 linear-gradient(to left, #ffffff, #000000);
     background-size: 8px 1px, 100% 1px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="divider">MEET OUR <span class="divider-2"> TEAM</span></h1>
```

You can get this by with background-image stacking.
In the first level you define the dotted itself:

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 50%, #ffffff 50%),
```

in the second one the whole gradient:

```
 linear-gradient(to right, #ffffff, #000000);
```

Than repeat the second one specular:

```
linear-gradient(to left, #ffffff, #000000);
```